# Get process list with logical intersection of selectors?

Tags: process, search, ps

The Linux `ps` command allows multiple selectors, such as user and command name, but always returns the logical OR of those selectors (more than I want). Does anyone know of a method or tool already made that can get the intersection (AND) of process selectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `pgrep`. Different selectors there are AND connected. The same connectors can be used in either AND or OR syntax.

**Example**: `pgrep -u user1,user2 -G 111 sshd` will list sshd-processes that belong to user1 OR user2 AND are in group 111.

Comment: cool, I didn't know about that one, yet it was already on my system. Thanks!

Comment: Don`t mind - that is our age. ;-) `pkill` is even more cool.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without `pgrep`? It is not available in my context.

Comment: @guettli in that case you are bound to `ps` for **or** and `|grep` for **and**